# Derivative of 1D Gaussian w.r.t mean and w.r.t x

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The three formulas (1D Gaussian, derivative w.r.t x, derivative w.r.t mean) are:

**One-dimensional Gaussian curve:**

[image: formula]

**One-dimensional Gaussian curve derivative w.r.t mean:**

[image: another]

**One-dimensional Gaussian curve derivative w.r.t x:**

[image: another]

When I plot the curves using a Python program (given below) using the above formulas for `mean = 0` and `sigma = 1`, I get the following curves:

[image]

**QUESTION:** I can understand the derivative of Gaussian w.r.t `x`. We have varied the values of `x` and the derivative w.r.t `x` represents how the curves change w.r.t `x`. But I am not able to understand why we get the same trend for the derivative of Gaussian w.r.t `mean`. The value of `mean` is constant for every computed point of the Gaussian curve so, the derivate w.r.t `mean` should not represent any change/dependence. Why are we getting the same `rate of change` trend w.r.t `x` as well as `mean`?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the range of x values
x_range = np.linspace(-8, 8, 100)

# Define the mean and standard deviation (sigma) for the Gaussian curve
mean = 0
sigma = 1

# Calculate the Gaussian values for the original Gaussian curve
gaussian_values = (1 / (sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))) * np.exp(-0.5 * ((x_range - mean) / sigma) ** 2)

# Calculate the derivative of the Gaussian curve with respect to the mean
derivative_mean = -gaussian_values * (x_range - mean) / (sigma ** 2)

# Calculate the derivative of the Gaussian curve with respect to x
derivative_x = (-1 / sigma) * gaussian_values * (x_range - mean)

# Create a plot to visualize the Gaussian curve and its derivatives
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

plt.plot(x_range, gaussian_values, label='Gaussian Curve', color='blue')
plt.plot(x_range, derivative_mean, label='Derivative w.r.t. Mean', color='red', linestyle='--')
plt.plot(x_range, derivative_x, label='Derivative w.r.t. X', color='green', linestyle=':')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.title('Gaussian Curve and Its Derivatives')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

# Show the plot
plt.show()

print('done')
```

Comment: The two rates of change differ by a factor of $-1$. Pay careful attention to the chain rule.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I am trying to understand the physical significance. Of course, if you put the values in the program with the above equations, you will get the curve. But the question is, why the derivative of Gaussian w.r.t mean (which is constant) is not zero?

Comment: You're asking how the Gaussian varies as you *vary* the mean, so it's no longer a fixed constant. Here's a simpler example. Let's consider $y=x+2c$. The graph is, of course, a line of slope $y$ and $y$-intercept $2c$. The derivative with respect to $x$ tells you the line has slope $1$. The derivative with respect to $c$ tells you that the line shifts up at rate $2$ as you vary $c$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Considering your example, I have done the same thing (i.e. computing derivatives w.r.t x and c) for the equation `f(x) = x + 2*x*c` (I made it 2xc). Again the derivative w.r.t `c` does not make sense to me (formulawise, I understand). The derivative w.r.t `c` is supposed to show you the change w.r.t `c` but we are only observing changes of f(x)/dc w.r.t x again.

Comment: It *is* showing you the change in the function (of both $x$ and $c$) as you change $c$. This is two-variable calculus. You have a function $f$ depending on $x$ and $c$. If you change $c$ a little bit $\Delta c$, then we have $f(x,c+\Delta c) \approx f(x,c) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial c}(x,c)\Delta c$. In your case, with $f(x,c) = (2c+1)x$, we have $f(x,c+\Delta c) = (2c+2\Delta c+1)x = f(x,c) + 2x\Delta c$. The rate at which the *value* changes depends on $x$.